# MFA is required? Container-based services

Tags: yodlee

I am using Container-based services, is there a way I can find out the container requires MFA or not after i have additemforcontentservice1?

Cheers,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call [getContentServiceInfo1](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getContentServiceInfo1) API before calling additemForContentService1 to know if the content service(the bank) requires MFA or not.

You need to look for the field "mfaType". This field will only be present for MFA sites with "typeName" as "TOKEN" or "IMAGE" or "SECURITY_QUESTION".

Also please follow the API flow [Add_Account](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Add_Account) and [Refresh_Account](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Refresh_Account)
for building the container based add account process.